# How do I create a menu that appears on hover?

Tags: css

I have a menu I created that I would like to appear on hover over of an image.  How do I write the css to create that?  This is my menu:

```
<ul id="options" class="optionsMenu">
    <li>A</li>
    <li>B</li>
    <li>C</li>
    <li>D</li>
    <li>E
        <ul>
            <li>E1</li>
            <li>E2</li>
            <li>E3</li>
            <li>E4</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>F</li>
    <li>G</li>
   </ul>
```

I would like it to stay hidden and only appear when I hover over the following image:

```
<img src='...image.png' alt='Options Menu' id="optionsMenuTree"/>
```

I think I need to do something like this:

```
#options ul.optionsMenu ul{
    display: none;
    visibility: none;
}
#optionsMenuTree:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
```

But I cannot get it to work right.  Any help?

Comment: Please see my updated answer for a CSS only solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CSS**

```
#options{
    display: none;
}
#optionsMenuTree:hover + #options {
    display: block;
}
```

Check this : http://jsfiddle.net/AliBassam/S9cdE/

However, when you remove the mouse of the image, the list will be hidden again, to keep it there, I think you need to use Javascript/JQuery.

**JQuery**

```
$("#optionsMenuTree").hover(function(){    
    $("#options").show();
}, function(){
    $("#options").hide();
});
```

**Javascript**

```
<img onmouseover="ShowList()" onmouseout="HideList()"/>
```

Then:

```
function ShowList()
{
    document.getElementById("options").style.display="block";
}
function HideList()
{
    document.getElementById("options").style.display="none";
}
```

Comment: It's good to mention it gonna works only if `#options` is child of `#optionsMenuTree`parent element, and image is placed before the menu

Comment: They are unrelated and rather far apart

Comment: @Christo Oh so you propably should mention it in your question. Now answer is clear - there is nothing you can do, use javascript.

Comment: @AliBassam edited your jquery part, I hope you are ok about it

Comment: @PeterSzymkowski It's ok, actually you need to ask **Christo** , whether he wants to hide the list if he removes the mouse or not.

Comment: @PeterSzymkowski none of this has worked so far... even the jquery

Comment: I want to hide the list on mouseout - its going to be a jump menu fired off of a dynatree

Comment: @Christo Check the Javascript solution

Comment: @Christo Maybe dumb question, but did did you include jquery in your page?

Answer (score 2):

As long as `optionsMenuTree` and `options` are siblings, you don't need javascript and can use

```
#options {
    display: none;
}

#optionsMenuTree:hover ~ #options {
    display: block;
}
```

See updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pr5ee/1/)

Comment: See his comment below Ali's answer _They [img and ul] are unrelated and rather far apart_. And where is image? :)

Comment: @PeterSzymkowski You mean like this?

Comment: Look Ali's answer and first comment :) `~` is not far away from `+`. Still menu+img _are unrelated and rather far apart_

Comment: @PeterSzymkowski Far apart doesn't matter. Although if unrelated means they're not siblings, it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

first you have to hide the submenu listitems. 
then have to show on hover or main link..

`ul#options ul {display: none;} ul#options ul li:hover > ul {   display: block; }`